# Pdf of $ Y = X^2 $ when $X$ is uniform on $[-1,1]$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution, density-function

Suppose you have $X\sim $ Uniform $[-1,1] $. $f_X(x)$= $\frac12, -1 \lt x \lt 1$, and $0$ otherwise.

$ Y = X^2 $.  Find the pdf of $Y$.

We know that $Y = X^2 $ will always be $\geq$ to $0$. I also know that
$F_Y(y)=P(Y\leq y)=P(X^2 \leq y) = P(\vert X \rvert \leq \sqrt{y}) = P(-\sqrt{y} \leq X \leq \sqrt{y}). $
I'm confused on how to trial certain values of Y to obtain the different ranges of the distribution function/ pdf.

Comment: Is it clear to you that $Y$ takes values in $[0,1]$? You are almost ready to find that $F_Y(y)=\sqrt y$ for $y\in[0,1]$. Then you can find PDF on $(0,1)$ by taking derivative. For other values the PDF takes value $0$. Actually I do not see your problem with this.

Comment: I think my main confusion is that how do you know that  _(y)=sqrt(y) for all y in (0,1), and isn't split up into different parts?

Comment: For an arbitrary $y\in[0,1]$ you (almost) found on a legitimite way that $F_{Y}(y)=\sqrt y$. That means exactly that this is true for *every* $y\in[0,1]$. Fortunately a split up into different parts was not necessary here. Do not allow yourself to get confused by other cases that have no jurisdiction here. Also note that $F(1)=\sqrt1=1$ and $F(0)=\sqrt0=0$ so the values of $F_Y$ on $[0,1]$ determine the CDF.

Answer (score 1):

You are right. You found

$F_Y(y)=F_X(\sqrt{y})-F_X(-\sqrt{y})=\sqrt{y}$

You have only to remember that $F_X(x)=\frac{x+1}{2}$.

Now deriving you get

$f_Y(y)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}}\mathbb{1}_{(0;1]}(y)$

Comment: Yes I obtained my distribution function of Y to be sqrt(y), but I'm not sure about the values of y for which the distribution function itself is sqrt(y). I'm getting this confusion because for other examples, you split up the transformed interval into parts and obtain new intervals which have their own distribution function.

Comment: @jeff123 : do a draw of the transformation function $Y=X^2$ in $x \in [-1;1]$ and you will immeditely see that Y-domain is $y \in (0;1]$. If you use the fundamental Transformation theorem you surely have to divide the interval in two parts as the transformation function is not monotone. Your procedure is right. Proceed always in this way and you will not do any errors